# Recursively audit smaller periods of time to identify source of discrepancy

Tags: python, database, etl

I have a data replication process that incrementally pulls data from an external source via API.  Occasionally, this process results in missed data due to race conditions, source errors, etc.  In an effort to audit the process, I would like to compare row counts over progressively smaller periods of time, until I identify the date from which the discrepancy occurred, and replicate that date only.  I am unable to pull row counts aggregated per date for all dates programmatically, I can only specify a single range and I need to limit my API calls.

The process flow should essentially follow:

- Compare row counts from inception to date.  If there's a mismatch:
- Compare row counts for each year (or period of 365 days) in the inception to date range.  Skip this step if the inception to date period is less than 1 year.  If there is still a mismatch:
- Compare row counts for each month (or period of 30 days) in the current year with a mismatch.  If there is still a mismatch:
- Compare row counts for each week (or period of 7 days) in the current month.  If there is still a mismatch:
- Compare row counts for each day in the current week.  The date with a mismatch should be re-replicated.

I was unable to come up with an elegant solution to this problem, this being the best attempt I've made thus far:

```
def backfill(start_ts: datetime.datetime, end_ts: datetime.datetime, replicate_process: typing.Callable, audit_process: typing.Callable) -> bool:
    brackets = [365, 30, 7, 1]
    funnel = [(end_ts - start_ts).days]
    funnel = sorted([i for i in brackets if i > funnel[0]], reverse=True)
    audit_bool = False

    increment_start = start_ts
    increment_end = end_ts

    while increment_start < increment_end:
        while not audit_bool:
            for days in funnel:
                audit_bool, increment_start, increment_end = audit_process(days, increment_start, increment_end)
                if days == 1:
                    replicate_process(increment_start, increment_end)
```

I've yet to figure out how to work in the loop over the specific range for each step in the process, and how to decide when the audit_process returning true means to exit the loop, versus continuing.

Is this a problem that has an idiomatic object oriented design pattern I'm unaware of?  To me it seems like the inverse of an exponential back-off, where you try exponentially smaller periods of time until the period is 1.  Although, in this case, the scale is date representations.

Comment: Ignore years months and days. Just use days and binary divide the period. For example, you have a pull between 20190101 and 20191031. Find the midpoint of that period and search between 20190101 and 20190530 then 20190531 and 20191031. You can send arbitrary dates to this API, right?

Comment: That makes so much more sense!  Yes, the dates can be arbitrary.  I was so focused on showing an audit failure for a month, then 3 successful and 1 failed audit in that month that I didn't even consider just using an arbitrary start and end date.